# Typescript compiler option alwaysStrict unavailable?

Tags: typescript, tsc

The [Compiler Options page on Typescript website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) lists the `--alwaysStrict` option, it's supposed to tell the compiler to emit "use strict" statements in the output.

Note that I'm working in Visual Studio Code.

I added the option in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        //... blah blah ...
```

But I get `Unknown compiler option 'alwaysStrict'` when attempting to build.

So, I ran `tsc` and see that the option isn't listed, here's the output copy-pasted from the cmd:

```
Version 2.0.9
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...]

Examples: tsc hello.ts
          tsc --outFile file.js file.ts
          tsc @args.txt

Options:
 --allowJs                           Allow javascript files to be compiled.
 --allowSyntheticDefaultImports      Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking.
 --allowUnreachableCode              Do not report errors on unreachable code.
 --allowUnusedLabels                 Do not report errors on unused labels.
 --baseUrl                           Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names.
 (blah blah, the rest of options alphabetically)
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `alwaysStrict` flag was added in version 2.1 as you can see in the [What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new---alwaysstrict).

Update your typescript version if you wish to use this flag.

Comment: Note to self: always double check the version of your packages... I fired `npm -g install typescript` and now I'm upgraded to `2.1.5` and the option is there.